# Integrating tensorflow objection detection api with centroid tracking algorithm of opencv

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, tensorflow

I am using object detection tutorial api to detect objects. So far it has been working fine. Now I am trying to integrate [centroid tracking algorithm](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/23/simple-object-tracking-with-opencv/) with the object detection api. To give a brief on what centroid tracking algorithm does is, it takes coordinates of bounding boxes i.e `Ymin, Xmin, Ymax, Xmax` and returns  `x, y` coordinates which correspond to the centroid of the given bounding boxes. Along with it, it also assigns id to an object.

My plan is to get the coordinates of the bounding boxes using tensorflow and feed it into the centroid tracking algorithm and then finally get the object id and centroid of the detected object.

The problem I am facing is that the tensorflow session returns the coordinates of the bounding box whose values are in decimals like `[(0.359079509973526, 0.2901528775691986, 0.9121878147125244, 0.8523546457290649)]` but the centroid tracker algorithm does not accept these values thus the final output comes out to be 0. If I update the bounding box values from `[(0.359079509973526, 0.2901528775691986, 0.9121878147125244, 0.8523546457290649)]` to `[(359.079509973526, 290.1528775691986, 912.1878147125244, 852.3546457290649)]` then it gives me output but it is not very accurate.

Has anyone integrated these two algorithms. How can I assign object id to the detected objects in tensorflow. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note tensorflow gives normalised co-ordinate values. You have to multiply them with height & width of frame: xmin * frame.shape[1], ymin * frame.shape[0], xmax * frame.shape[1], ymax * frame.shape[0]. This will solve your problem. Also, remember to check order of co-ordinates accepted by your tracker.